# Problem with metronic react theme to typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, authentication, redux, saga

It is v7.1.7 and uses saga middleware in react redux and is designed in JavaScript, not Typescript.
I have a problem in saga generator in authRedux.ts(original file is authRedux.js).
There's no error in authRedux.js but if I change it to .ts, 2 errors occur.

src/app/modules/Auth/_redux/authRedux.ts

```
import { AnyAction } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
import { persistReducer } from 'redux-persist';
import storage from 'redux-persist/lib/storage';
import { put, takeLatest } from 'redux-saga/effects';
import { getUserByToken } from './authCrud';

export const actionTypes = {
  Login: '[Login] Action',
  Logout: '[Logout] Action',
  Register: '[Register] Action',
  UserRequested: '[Request User] Action',
  UserLoaded: '[Load User] Auth API',
  SetUser: '[Set User] Action',
};

type TUser = string | undefined;
type TAuthToken = string | undefined;

export interface IAuth {
  user: TUser;
  authToken: TAuthToken;
}

const initialAuthState: IAuth = {
  user: undefined,
  authToken: undefined,
};

export const reducer = persistReducer<IAuth, AnyAction>(
  { storage, key: 'v713-demo1-auth', whitelist: ['user', 'authToken'] },
  (state: IAuth = initialAuthState, action: AnyAction) => {
    switch (action.type) {
      case actionTypes.Login: {
        const { authToken } = action.payload;
        return { authToken, user: undefined };
      }

      case actionTypes.Register: {
        const { authToken } = action.payload;
        return { authToken, user: undefined };
      }

      case actionTypes.Logout: {
        // TODO: Change this code. Actions in reducer aren't allowed.
        return initialAuthState;
      }

      case actionTypes.UserLoaded: {
        const { user } = action.payload;
        return { ...state, user };
      }

      case actionTypes.SetUser: {
        const { user } = action.payload;
        return { ...state, user };
      }

      default:
        return state;
    }
  },
);

export const actions = {
  login: (authToken: TAuthToken) => ({
    type: actionTypes.Login,
    payload: { authToken },
  }),
  register: (authToken: TAuthToken) => ({
    type: actionTypes.Register,
    payload: { authToken },
  }),
  logout: () => ({ type: actionTypes.Logout }),
  requestUser: (user: TUser) => ({
    type: actionTypes.UserRequested,
    payload: { user },
  }),
  fulfillUser: (user: TUser) => ({
    type: actionTypes.UserLoaded,
    payload: { user },
  }),
  setUser: (user: TUser) => ({ type: actionTypes.SetUser, payload: { user } }),
};

export function* saga() {
  yield takeLatest(actionTypes.Login, function* loginSaga() {
    //here is the first error. TypeScript error: Expected 1 arguments, but got 0.  TS2554
    yield put(actions.requestUser());
  });

  yield takeLatest(actionTypes.Register, function* registerSaga() {
    //here is the second error. TypeScript error: Expected 1 arguments, but got 0.  TS2554
    yield put(actions.requestUser());
  });

  yield takeLatest(actionTypes.UserRequested, function* userRequested() {
    const { data: user } = yield getUserByToken();
    yield put(actions.fulfillUser(user));
  });
}
```

I added comment where errors occur. It is in the saga() function which is saga generator.
How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Your `requestUser` action creator takes a `user` object as an argument:

```
requestUser: (user: TUser) => ({
  type: actionTypes.UserRequested,
  payload: { user },
}),
```

When switching to `.ts`, typescript is able to detect function calls that are missing their required arguments.  You are dispatching this `requestUser` action creator from your saga without passing it a `user` argument:

```
// TypeScript error: Expected 1 arguments, but got 0.  TS2554
yield put(actions.requestUser());
```

You have handled this correctly in your `userRequested`/`fulfillUser` saga where you access the `user` object from `getUserByToken` and then pass it to your action creator.  You will need to do the same or similar in your `loginSaga` and `registerSaga` in order to call `actions.requestUser` properly.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
But I can't understand why this metronic theme is missing the argument.
You said I would need to do the same or similar as user requested saga, but how can i get user? There's no token before login or register.
I can remove this saga, but I want to know why metronic is missing the argument.
Or how to fix it in details.

Comment: Ok I didn't quite understand that this was not your code which you were converting to TS.  If they are calling `requestUser` with no `user` then the type for `requestUser` should have the `user` as an optional argument `requestUser: (user?: TUser) => ({` Or maybe not have `user` as an argument at all?  Are there other places where you call `requestUser(user)`?  This action is only used by the saga and not by the reducer so that should be okay.

Comment: I think I can insert necessary code above the yield put(). For ex, http axios call to get authorized user name and set it to the argument of requestUser(). In fact, they only receive access_token when registered or logined. I changed this code to receive token with user name. But They meant I should insert it here in the saga middleware, I think. Thank you.